# How do i filter the tables i do not need when I use "include"?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

My EF nightmare continue. I noticed when I use eager loading `include` all related table will retrieve to my application. So for example 1 have 3 tables/POCO like below, from below POCO and linq i just want to retrieve 2 tables but however when i check the generate T-SQL all 3 tables will retrieve, How do I exclude the table 3?

**Poco**

```
public class TableA{
   public virtual ICollection<TableB> B { get; set; }
}

public class TableB{
   public virtual ICollection<TableC> C { get; set; }
}

public class TableC{

}
```

**LINQ**

```
var rs =(from family in context.A.Include("B")
select family).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well, ideally, don't use eager loading. Unless there's a reason you have to that you're not telling us...

Comment: Show the actual code and use case.  The query has no reason to pull table C, so it shouldn't be doing so, which leads me to believe you have left something out.

Comment: As @PhilSandler says there is no reason why Table C should be loaded. For further testing I would remove your Include statements and turn off lazy loading for the desired tables. Look at this article for a how to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want fine grain control on which entities get loaded, use :

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Note that for each instance of your DbContext, you can either get the lazy loading, OR the eager loading.

You shouldn't try to use both on the same instance.